# How to use Angular Custom Directive properly?

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, angular-directive

MY HTML:-

```
<li [routerLink]="['/admin']" *allowedUIAccess="'ADMIN'"
                [permissionSet]="(userprofile$ | async)?.permissions">
                Admin
            </li>
```

MY DIRECTIVE:-

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[allowedUIAccess]'
})
export class AllowedUIAccessDirective {

  @Input()
  permissionSet!: string[] | undefined;

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef,
    private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>, private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef,
    private uiService: UiService) {
  }

  @Input()
  set allowedUIAccess(condition: string) {
    console.log(condition);
    console.log(this.permissionSet);
  }

}
```

ERROR :-

error TS2322: Type '"(userprofile$ | async)?.permissions"' is not assignable to type 'string[] | undefined'.

13                 permissionSet="(userprofile$ | async)?.permissions">

How I can resolve this error where I am wrong please help.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `permissionSet` attribute takes its value from an observable it makes sense to also handle it with a setter:

```
  @Input()
  set permissionSet(permissions: string[] | undefined) {
    console.log(permissions);
  }
```

Also, I got a syntax error caused by the asterisk in `*allowedUIAccess="'ADMIN'"`. When you change it to:

```
[allowedUIAccess]="'ADMIN'"
```

Or

```
allowedUIAccess="ADMIN"
```

Everything works as expected.

With these fixes it seems to work for me, check out this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ufmdjq?file=src/app/allowed-ui-access.directive.ts)